# why window is not showing up

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

`pip install tk`

`pip install googletrans`

`!apt-get install -y xvfb # Install X Virtual Frame Buffer import os os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')  # start it os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0'  # tells X clients where to connect to`

`window = tk.Tk() window.mainloop()`

this is my code, i donno y window is not getting popped up and it is creating a infinite loop.

is it my laptop prob or is it a code prob!!!!
please help me with this

Comment: `pip install tk` installs tensorkit, not tkinter. You can't install tkinter with pip.